# Proper way to handle CosmosDb Mongo 429 error with Polly

Tags: mongodb, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I deploy an application on azure web apps who interract with a CosmosDB database using the mongoDb driver in .netCore 3.

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/http-status-codes-for-cosmosdb) documentation I have to set a retry policy in order to handle the 429 error code when the RU/s are not available. I can't find a proper way to handle the policy with Polly given the fact that I haven't seen one the error display when the 429 error happends.

The only proper way to do it is by using the following Policy :

```
_retryPolicy = Policy
.Handle<MongoCommandException>(r => r.Message.Contains("Request rate is large"))
.WaitAndRetry(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

And here is the use of the Polly policy :

```
   public long CountProjetByProjectNumber(string projectNumber)
    {
        long result = 0;
        _retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
        {
            result = _mongoCollection.CountDocuments(x => x.ProjectNumber == projectNumber);
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Do someone have the correct error display when the 429 exception happends in CosmosDb with the Mongodb driver or can someone show me the way he handled it properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is actually a few more exceptions you'll have to handle in order to properly handle rate limiting and timeouts - especially when using the newer MongoDB V3.6 endpoint (as opposed to the older V3.2 endpoint).

> - **For V3.2 Endpoints**: The two exceptions you care about is the `MongoCommandException` and `MongoExecutionTimeoutException`. The
>     `MongoCommandException` includes a `BsonDocument` property in its
>     `Result` field. This document has a `StatusCode` you can use to detect 429. That said, from my testing, I also found that I had to handle Http Service Unavailable (1) and Operation Exceeded Time Limit
>     (50) status codes.
> - **For V3.6 Endpoints**: You probably also want to handle `MongoWriteException` and `MongoBulkWriteException`. These exceptions
>     include a `RetryAfterMs=` value **in the exception message** (not
>     always though!). Unfortunately, this value does not seem to be
>     directly exposed via a class property - most likely because this is
>     a CosmosDB specific feature and thus does not map to the MongoDB
>     driver defined exceptions.

The below code is implemented in .NET Standard 2.0 and should give you more than a good starting point. You will definitely want to tweak some of the constants based on your circumstances and testing.

```
    public static class Policies
    {
        public const int HttpThrottleErrorCode = 429;
        public const int HttpServiceIsUnavailable = 1;
        public const int HttpOperationExceededTimeLimit = 50;
        public const int RateLimitCode = 16500;
        public const string RetryAfterToken = "RetryAfterMs=";
        public const int MaxRetries = 10;
        public static readonly int RetryAfterTokenLength = RetryAfterToken.Length;

        private static readonly Random JitterSeed = new Random();

        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy NoPolicy = Policy.NoOpAsync();

        public static Func<int, TimeSpan> SleepDurationProviderWithJitter(double exponentialBackoffInSeconds, int maxBackoffTimeInSeconds) => retryAttempt
            => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Min(Math.Pow(exponentialBackoffInSeconds, retryAttempt), maxBackoffTimeInSeconds)) // exponential back-off: 2, 4, 8 etc
               + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(JitterSeed.Next(0, 1000)); // plus some jitter: up to 1 second

        public static readonly Func<int, TimeSpan> DefaultSleepDurationProviderWithJitter =
            SleepDurationProviderWithJitter(1.5, 23);


        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy MongoCommandExceptionPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<MongoCommandException>(e =>
            {
                if (e.Code != RateLimitCode || !(e.Result is BsonDocument bsonDocument))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (bsonDocument.TryGetValue("StatusCode", out var statusCode) && statusCode.IsInt32)
                {
                    switch (statusCode.AsInt32)
                    {
                        case HttpThrottleErrorCode:
                        case HttpServiceIsUnavailable:
                        case HttpOperationExceededTimeLimit:
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                if (bsonDocument.TryGetValue("IsValid", out var isValid) && isValid.IsBoolean)
                {
                    return isValid.AsBoolean;
                }

                return true;
            })
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                retryCount: MaxRetries,
                DefaultSleepDurationProviderWithJitter
            );

        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy ExecutionTimeoutPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<MongoExecutionTimeoutException>(e =>
                e.Code == RateLimitCode || e.Code == HttpOperationExceededTimeLimit
            )
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                retryCount: MaxRetries,
                DefaultSleepDurationProviderWithJitter
            );

        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy MongoWriteExceptionPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<MongoWriteException>(e =>
            {
                return e.WriteError?.Code == RateLimitCode
                       || (e.InnerException is MongoBulkWriteException bulkException &&
                           bulkException.WriteErrors.Any(error => error.Code == RateLimitCode));
            })
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                retryCount: MaxRetries,
                sleepDurationProvider: (retryAttempt, e, ctx) =>
                {
                    var timeToWaitInMs = ExtractTimeToWait(e.Message);
                    if (!timeToWaitInMs.HasValue && e.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        timeToWaitInMs = ExtractTimeToWait(e.InnerException.Message);
                    }
                    return timeToWaitInMs ?? DefaultSleepDurationProviderWithJitter(retryAttempt);
                },
                onRetryAsync: (e, ts, i, ctx) => Task.CompletedTask
            );

        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy MongoBulkWriteExceptionPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<MongoBulkWriteException>(e =>
            {
                return e.WriteErrors.Any(error => error.Code == RateLimitCode);
            })
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                retryCount: MaxRetries,
                sleepDurationProvider: (retryAttempt, e, ctx) =>
                {
                    var timeToWaitInMs = ExtractTimeToWait(e.Message);
                    return timeToWaitInMs ?? DefaultSleepDurationProviderWithJitter(retryAttempt);
                },
                onRetryAsync: (e, ts, i, ctx) => Task.CompletedTask
            );

        /// <summary>
        /// It doesn't seem like RetryAfterMs is a property value - so unfortunately, we have to extract it from a string... (crazy??!)
        /// </summary>
        private static TimeSpan? ExtractTimeToWait(string messageToParse)
        {
            var retryPos = messageToParse.IndexOf(RetryAfterToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (retryPos >= 0)
            {
                retryPos += RetryAfterTokenLength;
                var endPos = messageToParse.IndexOf(',', retryPos);
                if (endPos > 0)
                {
                    var timeToWaitInMsString = messageToParse.Substring(retryPos, endPos - retryPos);
                    if (Int32.TryParse(timeToWaitInMsString, out int timeToWaitInMs))
                    {
                        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeToWaitInMs)
                               + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(JitterSeed.Next(100, 1000));
                    }
                }
            }
            return default;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this policy if your CosmosDB MongoDB endpoint is V3.2
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy DefaultPolicyForMongo3_2 = Policy.WrapAsync(MongoCommandExceptionPolicy, ExecutionTimeoutPolicy);

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this policy if your CosmosDB MongoDB endpoint is V3.6 or V3.2
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly IAsyncPolicy DefaultPolicyForMongo3_6 = Policy.WrapAsync(MongoCommandExceptionPolicy, ExecutionTimeoutPolicy, MongoWriteExceptionPolicy, MongoBulkWriteExceptionPolicy);
    }

    public static IAsyncPolicy DefaultPolicy { get; set; } = Policies.DefaultPolicyForMongo3_6;
```